# how to change an item in an array using the useState hook in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

let's say I have an array of 1 and I want to change index 2, how do I change that state?

```
const [state, setState] = useState([1,1,1,1]);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. When asking questions it is suggested to also demonstrate what you've tried and point to what isn't working for you. Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Rather than give us a requirement and starting point, you need to show us what you tried to solve the problem. Without that information it looks like you didn't try and want us to solve it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The second item of useState()'s array has a callback function.

```
setState( prevState => {
  const newState = [...prevState]
  newState[2] = 2
  return newState
})
```